# How can I translate the expression "I don't care" into Italian?

Tags: translation

In English we use the expression "I don't care" to express that we don't feel interest or concern about something. How can we say a similar expression in Italian? Google Translate gives "Non mi interessa", which I think it's "It doesn't interest me", so probably there are better translations. It would be interesting to learn a variety of idiomatic expressions which convey this sense that can be used in different situations.

Comment: Non mi frega niente. This is Perugino dialect and essentially means "I don't give a damn".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Non mi interessa* is correct, but perhaps not always strong enough. You might want to say:

- *non m'importa* (the most neutral and standard solution), its variant *chi se ne importa* (= who cares?) or the stronger *non me ne importa niente*;
- *non me ne frega niente* (even stronger) or its variants *chi se ne frega?* and *me ne frego* (the latter of which, however, has Fascist overtones, since it was used as a kind of motto by the Blackshirts);
- *me ne infischio*;
- then there are some truly vulgar versions, such as *me ne sbatto* (optionally: *me ne sbatto i coglioni* and the like).

Comment: As a side note, "me ne infischio" was popularized because it was chosen as the italian translation for the famous "I don't give a damn" that Rhett Butler (Clark Gable) says in "gone with the wind" ("via col vento"). https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francamente_me_ne_infischio

Comment: One of my professor always says "Me ne faccio un baffo", which I consider nice and not vulgar.

Comment: Some variants: "Non me ne frega un fico secco" and "Non me ne puó fregare di meno"

Comment: Also "Non me ne importa un tubo"

Comment: I'd add *"chissenefrega"* as a very colloquial option.